# How to use functions in a inline HTML translate pipe?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-translate, ngx-translate

My goal is to minimize the code using the Angular translate pipe. Currently, I have to use 8 curly brackets and write "translate" twice... a better way must exist.

My current code looks like:

```
<span
  *ngIf="checkoutForm.get('email')?.errors?.['email']">
  {{ 'eMail' | translate }} {{ lowerCaseFirstLetter('isInvalid' | translate) }}
</span>
```

And I'm trying to do shorten it in something like

```
<span
  *ngIf="checkoutForm.get('email')?.errors?.['email']" 
  translate>eMail {{ lowerCaseFirstLetter('isInvalid' | translate) }}
</span>
```

or maybe even

```
<span
  *ngIf="checkoutForm.get('email')?.errors?.['email']"
   translate>eMail lowerCaseFirstLetter('isInvalid')
</span>
```

##### The Text

email *is a translation* = E-Mail
isInvalid *is a translation* = Is invalid
lowerCaseFirstLetter() *is a function which just lowercases first letter* this is important to not destroy the orthography in other languages

Comment: What is your end goal and what does this lowerCaseFirstLetter does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a custom pipe that accepts an extra parameter so you can do this:

```
<span
    *ngIf="checkoutForm.get('email')?.errors?.['email']"> 
    {{ 'eMail' | error:'isInvalid' }}
</span>
```

for that create a pipe file `error.pipe.ts` with following content:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';

@Pipe({
          name: 'error'
})

export class ErrorPipe implements PipeTransform {
          constructor(private translateService: TranslateService) {
          }
          transform(value: string, arg: string): string {
                    return `${this.translateService.instant(value)} ${this.translateService.instant(arg).toLowerCase()}`;
          }
}
```

declare it in the component module you want to use it in `example.module.ts`:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';  // standard
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';  // standard
import { ErrorPipe } from './path/to/error.pipe';

@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule, ExampleRoutingModule], // standard
  declarations: [ExampleComponent, ErrorPipe]
})
export class ExampleModule {}
```

now you can do following thing in the component:

```
<span
    *ngIf="checkoutForm.get('email')?.errors?.['email']"> 
    {{ 'eMail' | error:'isInvalid' }}
</span>
```

Comment: I've added a step-by-step guide to your comment how I've been able to solve to problem. Thank you for the idea!

Comment: @jorit thanks for the step-by-step, I've updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

you can create a translate directive like the 3 code block

```js
@Directive({
  selector: '[translate]'
})
export class TranslateDirective implements AfterViewInit {

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) { }

   ngAfterViewInit() {
    const translatedText = translate(this.el.nativeElement.innerText)
    this.el.nativeElement.innerText = translatedText;
  }
}
```

```html
<span
  *ngIf="checkoutForm.get('email')?.errors?.['email']"
   translate>eMail lowerCaseFirstLetter('isInvalid')
</span>
```